# ASP.NET screenshot page

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, bitmap, screenshot

Related Stack Overflow question is *[Programmatically get a screenshot of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981670)*.

My users will be logged into a private system, and I want to have a button on the page that says "Take Screenshot". This will link into the support system, and when they take the screen shot, it creates a new ticket with the screen shot as an automatic attachment.

Content is variable, depending on who you are logged in as! This means I can't use an external screen shotting tool.

Ideally, I would like all the HTML to be rendered to a bitmap which is saved to a disk. Is there some sort of server-side Internet Explorer component that can render the HTML and save it as a BMP?

Kierren made good points. If I can grab the HTML via JavaScript, is there any server-side plugin that can render the HTML as an image as viewed through Internet Explorer?

Comment: This will *not* be a screenshot: it won't include any errors or problems introduced by the browser, internet connection, firewall, content filtering - depending on how you render the page it also won't include form field values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some unsuccesful attempts with that in the past. I could not get the solution which works seemlessly but here are some I have had near-sucess (i.e. for most of the URLs) [Since I was doing POC, results did not matter] See if that helps

[WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() or other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-or-other-methods)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)-to-bitmap converter before, but there are definitely HTML-to-[PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) options,

http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/

and

http://html-pdf-converter.com/

to name a couple.