# How TeamViewer is able to take a screenshot of the login screen?

Tags: windows, screenshot

I made an application that takes screen shots of the screen periodically. Then I wrapped it in windows service and tried to capture screen shots in background. I wanted to take screen shots even logged off. I wanted to take a screen shot of the login screen too but without success. The application works but when logged off the image is black.

I tried using GDI, Windows API, DirectX and neither of these methods works. The result is the same. Black image. The last technology to try is Windows Media API although I'm not sure that I will succeed.

Do someone hase an idea what can be done ?

I want achieve something Teamviewer or Ultra VNC can.

Comment: GDI didn't work?? Surprising. . .

Comment: Besides that GDI raises Invalid Handle exception while running in web service when logged of from Windows. I think when the user is logged of the Desktop is not initialized so the image of the desktop is black. Maybe interacting with the Video memory or the Video driver could solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get screenshot of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981670/programmatically-get-screenshot-of-page)

Comment: How are you dealing with session 0 isolation?